How can I get a ratio based on grouped column?

I'm trying to do a select statement and get the ratio of adult and children over the total based on the other columns. i.e. What is the ratio of Adult and Children for 202208, NV, Medicaid? I can do this in Excel by putting QTY/Sumifs().

We don't post pictures of data here.
